# HTTP RESPONSE when a path Variable is blank in a PUT method

Tags: java, rest, http-response-codes

I’m trying to find the best pracice on what type of response should I send when a path parameter in a REST service is blank or null when using a PUT method.

For example, imagine we have the following resource:

> PUT report/{report-id}/client/{client-id}

Should I validate that the parameter  report-id and  client-id are not null or blank?

If they are blank or null I can think of two types of messages:

- Return a 400 response with a message indicating that a mandatory
  parameter is missing.
- Return a 404 response, indicating that we can’t create or update the resource because that resource dosn’t exist?

I don't think there is a standard convention of doing it. Is there? However, I would like to hear opinions on what's the best practice to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The specification for REST might be insightful here:

> The key abstraction of information in REST is a resource. Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource. A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time.

Since the lack of a resource cannot logically be given a name it can never exist in REST. As a consequence I think you'd find that most public APIs will return `404`. Take getting a user's information from GitHub for example. The documentation states that a user can be found at `https://api.github.com/users/{username}`. https://api.github.com/users/ (notice the trailing slash) returns `404`. Regardless of what the HTTP spec says (although following it is always a good idea) if you adhere to the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) returning `404` is your best bet.

As a side note, when naming resources the convention is that collections should be plural. So, for your example you would actually want the resource to look more like: `/reports/{report-id}/clients/{client-id}`. Especially when dealing with 'empty' parameters it will make it much clearer exactly what the request was for.

Answer (score 0):

> I’m trying to find the best practice on what type of response should I send when a path parameter in a REST service is blank or null when using a PUT method.

An important thing to understand is that the *body* of the response is available to you to describe in detail what the actual problem is.  See RFC [7231, section 6.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5)

> the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

The status code is metadata, which allows general-purpose components to understand what is going on.  The metadata all belongs to the uniform interface, which is to say it is of the "transferring documents over a network" domain.

In this case, I think your best fit for a status code is [403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.